# How is "How do I say..." different from "How do I phrase..."?

Tags: discussion

This is with reference to my post [How do I tell a friend I don't want to play their game anymore, but invite them to mine](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11787/how-do-i-tell-a-friend-i-dont-want-to-play-their-game-anymore-but-invite-them)
which is about to be closed as "not a good fit"

How is what I am asking any different to "how do I say"? just because I know it has to be done via email?

Answer (score 1):

"How do I say" covers the whole ***interpersonal approach*** to communicating something to someone without asking this site to supply suggestions about the *wording/ phrasing* which is, strictly speaking, ***"what do I say"*** and is considered off-topic here. Hence the early close votes.

However, your question has been edited usefully by a member to remove the email phrasing request and concentrate on the "how to effectively communicate" element, so the Q looks all right now and probably won't get closed, although you could possibly **add more details** relevant to the interpersonal equation between you and this friend, so that members can provide better answers here.

If it gets closed you can make the necessary improvements (editing help can be requested on chat or meta) and then apply here for reopening.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your initial question, it was:

> How do I word this email please?

Which  is something we don't do, [we aren't a "how to write" site](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/is-how-to-write-off-topic-on-ips). However  we will be able to offer advice on how to *communicate* with someone else. In this format of your question you aren't appearing to focus on the actual interpersonal skill, and more on the "Please help me write an email to tell A X."

Thankfully, another member of the community has worded it to be more appropriate as an IPS question:

> How can I tactfully inform our friend that they will no longer host our game without offending them?

This asks the question of *how* you can inform your friends that you will be doing what you are doing, without offending them. This isn't focusing on what you can and can't say, but more what sort of tone you should use, and what certain phrases would do well.

The current answer actually does give you an example email to send, however answers should really instead simply give you guidance to write your own, explaining how you should say it, and if believed to be necessary including small sentences that would be useful to have in your email.

Ultimately our end goal is to *teach* you the interpersonal skills necessary so you can apply them yourself to your current situation - rather than just dealing with it for you. A useful analogy may be to think of it as homework, your first question was essentially asking us to do it for you, however the current format is more focused on asking us to help teach you the things you need to know to do the homework yourself.

Comment: *"Looking at your initial question, it was:

    How do I word this email please?

Which is something we don't do (...) The current answer actually does give you an example email to send, however answers should really instead simply give you guidance to write your own"* __ Very well explained @Crafter. That leads us to the matter of **what to do with answers that specifically write the communication** for an OP (even if only as an "example" or "sample" which might well be the whole email depending on the scope of OP's intentions) when the wording or "what to communicate" is off topic here.