# Why was my etiquette question closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

Edit:

I've now added more specific information to my question, according to Catija's comment - can we get it reopened?

My question here

[Etiquette question regarding conveying enthusiasm in email communications - used in academic settings](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/13066/etiquette-question-regarding-conveying-enthusiasm-in-email-communications-used)

was closed as off-topic, which is baffling.

Why is the question closed as off-topic?

Comment: If you're trying to convince someone, providing arguments to support your claim goes much further than saying "It's clearly x". Obviously people thought it was off topic, otherwise they wouldn't have voted to close it as such. Why do you think that it's on topic?

Comment: Can you provide some arguments to support your claim that it was "Contentiously done". I'd suggest removing the bit where you are assuming ill faith of other members of this site. It's not very nice.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the question closed as off-topic?

It isn't that baffling if you consider [the first revision of your question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/revisions/cf4770c9-72a1-4f6a-b625-b6c7a1aed0db/view-source), which was basically asking for writing style guidelines on the header of your e-mail. Such stuff was discussed on meta [before](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2207/1599), and since no-one counteracted it, I left a comment explaining this site isn't the place to find out whether an exlamation mark is appropriate or not. *Writing Skills aren't Interpersonal Skills, Writing etiquette is something different than Interpersonal etiquette.*

> I've now added more specific information to my question, according to Catija's comment - can we get it reopened?

In my opinion, no. Although you've deftly rephrased portions of the question, it's still asking if a certain kind of header (with an exclamation mark) for an e-mail is appropriate. That's to me still asking about a writing skill, not an Interpersonal Skill.